# cost-intense sql operations (multiple union with multiple joins)

Tags: mysql, database, join, union

as the title says, I need to create a query over several tables which have the title-pattern (4 tables each for a project):

- T_project1_Tablename1
- T_project1_Tablename2
- T_project1_Tablename3
- T_project1_Tablename4
- T_project2_Tablename1
- T_project2_Tablename2
- T_project2_Tablename3
- T_project2_Tablename4
- ...

**I create one "big" query for each project** (Select T_project1_Tablename1 LEFT JOIN T_project1_Tablename2 ON() LEFT JOIN T_project1_Tablename3 ON() LEFT JOIN T_project1_Tablename4 ON() WHERE...)
**and combine it with "Union"** with the other project-queries to get all data from all projects.

**My question is**: I have measured the execution time in myphpAdmin and even for only one union of two queries, it takes 20 seconds "sending data". This is inacceptable, since I need to combine up to 20 of these project informations.

Are there any best-practices of how this is done? Have I missed any "tricks" or should I do one query after one (which takes only 1 second each)?

pls make suggestions!

Comment: What is the "title pattern"?  In terms of speed, did you run `EXPLAIN` and make sure you had indexes?

Comment: It sounds as though your database has a design issue, duplicating tables for different projects. Further using UNION will attempt to delete duplicates and will take a while to do that (you probably want to use UNION ALL).  Also double check your join conditions as it would be rather easy for one of those joins to land up as a cross join, massively increasing the number of returned rows.